# Android Developer Dashboard national/regional version

Tags: android, version, dashboard, platform, regional

As many of you may know, Google has provided us with a nice [Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) that shows us the current distribution of active Android devices along certain characteristics, such as platform version or screen size.

It would be nice to have some similar information, but counting devices only in a specific region or country. For example, I am a Hungarian developer currently working on applications that are almost certainly only useful for people living here, in Hungary. Thus, I don't need to know the world's statistics, only the Hungarian subset - which would be slightly different due to lesser and later availability of the devices and general economical reasons.

So far I could not find such statistics, so I ask you, have you ever stumbled upon something like that? Or shall I write to Google and ask for this seemingly not too complicated feature?

Comment: Agreed. Global Android version is only useful for some apps. Many, many are targeted geographically. Developing for the UK market, I suspect the Gingerbread share is lower - but I just don't know!

Comment: Localytics has some US data: http://readwrite.com/2013/03/06/android-23-gingerbread-death-throes

Comment: Google is an AI, it doesn't listen to mortal developers

Answer (score 1):

You could implement Google Analytics ( https://www.google.com.br/analytics/ ) on your app. There you can find all kinds of statistics, including country specific data.

Here is how to implement Analytics on you Android App: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/

Comment: While this gives data for current users, it doesn't help with the available market for a given region.

Answer (score 0):

It would be awesome if we had this from Google.  There are a couple of sites/blogs that occasionally post info that can give you an idea.  Device Atlas uses "mobile web data" - who knows what that means exactly but their numbers seem reasonable.

https://deviceatlas.com/blog/android-versions-market-share-2017

You can replace the "2017" with "2016" to get last year's report.  Maybe they will have more in the future.